# ColumnFamily Design: Index or map in second CF?

Tags: cassandra

I got a question, I would appreciate any help.

Lets suppose I need a cf with orders, and columns OrderId, UserID, InsDate.
I need to get all orders of a user.

What would be the optimal design?
Have an index on UserID and search directly the Order CF?
Or create a cf UserOrders that will hold a map of orders per User (with UserID as row key)?

Using the second approach, I would search UserOrders for the row of the User with all its orders and then select * from Orders where OrderID IN ()

I have read that the second approach would perform better when data and clients grow, as each select will run on CF row keys only.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get all orders of a user then it would make sense to use the first approach, e.g.,

Table Creation:

```
create table orders(
  userid int, 
  orderid int, 
  insDate timeuuid,
  primary key(userid,orderid)
);
```

Insertion:

```
insert into orders(userid, orderid, insDate) VALUES(1, 1, now());
insert into orders(userid, orderid, insDate) VALUES(1, 2, now());
insert into orders(userid, orderid, insDate) VALUES(2, 3, now());
insert into orders(userid, orderid, insDate) VALUES(3, 4, now());
```

Querying:

```
 >select userid,dateof(insdate),orderid from orders where userid in(1,2);

userid | dateof(insdate)          | orderid
--------+--------------------------+---------
      1 | 2013-11-06 17:26:56+0000 |       1
      1 | 2013-11-06 17:26:59+0000 |       2
      2 | 2013-11-06 17:27:02+0000 |       3

(3 rows)
```

(Tested with `[cqlsh 4.0.1 | Cassandra 2.0.1 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.37.0]`.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My case is more complicated though, I can't add the UserId in the primary key, hence my question on the Index / Secondary CF

Comment: But you do need to get all orders by user? What's the reason for not using userId in the primary key?

Comment: The case here is simplified. In reality the table is more complex and the primary key consists of 4 columns that cover some other scenarios. The UserId cannot definitely be the clustering key. I could use it as a last column in the primary key, but that would mean application complexity that I would rather avoid now. If I find out that it is absolutely necessary, I will do it though. I just hoped I would get away with an index or a secondary cf.

Comment: My recommendation would be either to use userid as the final primary key or to use a second table with the same data, optimised for those types of queries. A second table reduces complexity at the cost of extra storage and is a pretty typical approach - storage is cheap.